# Objective-c Check if calendar exists

Tags: objective-c, nscalendar

I searched a lot and even if this question seems simple seems there is no clear answers. How do I retrieve a calendar programmatically? I need to save one and avoid to create it if it already has been saved.

I did something like:

```
myEventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
EKEvent *myEvent = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:myEventStore];
[myEvent setCalendar:[myEventStore calendarWithIdentifier:@"Infinity"]];
```

And checked if "myEvent" was nil, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can list the calendars by `[EKEventStore calendars]`, in iOS 6 deprecated in favor of `[EKEventStore calendarsForEntityType:]`.